# Exercise with change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I need help to solve this exercise

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a diffeomorphism of class $C^1$ such that $f(B)\subseteq B$, where $B$ is the closed unitary ball of $R^m$ and $|\text{det}Df(x)|<1$ for all $x\in B$. Show that, for a continuous function $g:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{f^n(B)}g(x)dx=0$ where $f^n=fofo..f$, corresponds to $n$-compositions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\left|\det \mathop{D}f\right|$ and $g$ are continuous on the compact set $B$.
Thus there exist $x_0$, $x_1$ such that
$$
s := \sup_{x∈B}\left|\det \mathrm{D}f(x)\right| = \left|\det \mathrm{D}f(x_0)\right| < 1
$$
and
$$
g_0 := \sup_{x∈B}g(x) = g(x_1).
$$

With this and the substitution rule, it follows that for all $n$,

$$
{\int\limits_{f^n(B)} g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x}
= {\int\limits_{f(f^{n-1}(B))} g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x}
= {\int\limits_{f^{n-1}(B)}g(f(x)) \cdot \left|\det \mathrm{D}f(x)\right| \,\mathrm{d}x}
≤ {\int\limits_{f^{n-1}(B)}g_0 \cdot s \,\mathrm{d}x}
≤ {s \cdot \int\limits_{f^{n-1}(B)}g_0 \,\mathrm{d}x}
$$
holds.

Can you figure out the rest?

Comment: Is it possible to do this? $$
{\int\limits_{f^n(B)} g(x_1) \,\mathrm{d}x_1}
= {\int\limits_{f(f^{n-1}(B))} g(x_1) \,\mathrm{d}x_1}
= {\int\limits_{f^{n-1}(B)}g(f(x_2)) \cdot \left|\det \mathrm{D}f(x_2)\right| \,\mathrm{d}x_2}≤ {s \cdot \int\limits_{f^{n-1}(B)}g(f(x_2)) \,\mathrm{d}x}
≤...$$ and using this repeatedly.

Comment: It seems you are on the right track, but your notation is somewhat confusing. I’m not sure where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are constants and where they are variables in your equation.

Comment: In my considerations $x_1$ and $x_2$ are variables. But I already realized about the solution for my problem. Thanks.